# A possible ambiguity of constructor in C++

Tags: c++, constructor

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct A {
    A(int i) {
        cout << "1 args" << endl;
    }
    A(int i, int j) {
        cout << "2 args" << endl;
    }
};

void foo(int i) {
    cout << "1 args" << endl;
}
void foo(int i, int j) {
    cout << "2 args" << endl;
}

int main() {
    int i, j;
    A(i, j);
    (A)(i, j);
    foo(i, j);
    (foo)(i, j);
}
```

Output:

```
2 args
1 args
2 args
2 args
```

I know the result "1 args" is because "(i, j)" is evaluated as "j".

But what's the reason of the difference considering constructors are also functions?

Comment: Constructors are not functions in the sense you are interpreting.   `(A)(i,j)` is a type conversion, not an explicit call of `A`s constructor.  You could achieve the same thing as `static_cast<A>(i,j)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Constructors are member functions; If you wanted to try to "call a constructor" like any other function, the code might be `a.A(i,j);` using the member access operator on some object `a` that you already created. But this is not allowed, because constructors are only called as part of object creation.

1. `A(i, j);` matches the syntax *`postfix-expression:` `simple-type-specifier`* `(` *`expression-list`* `)`. The meaning of that syntax is a prvalue expression creating that type, with the expression-list being the constructor arguments.
2. `(A)(i, j);` does not match that syntax because *`simple-type-specifier`* cannot be parenthesized.  However it does match *`cast-expression`* , so it is the expression `(i, j)` (which is a comma operator expression) cast to `A`.  The result of casting to a class type involves, in this case, constructing a temporary of that class type.
3. `foo(i, j);` matches *`postfix-expression:` `postfix-expression`* `(` *`expression-list`* `)`, which is a call to function `foo` with that argument list
4. `(foo)(i, j);` also matches that same rule, since `(` *`postfix-expression`* `)` is still a *`postfix-expression`*.

Comment: I have ever used Bison to write a parser. Your answer is clear enough to me.

Answer (score 0):

For those looking for a *less technical* answer, I'd read the [M.M answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43601302/4783169) like:

**A** is a **type** and **foo isn't**, so:

```
(A)(i, j);    // cast to A the result of (i, j) ==> calls A(j) in conversion
(foo)(i, j)   // still the same as foo(i, j)
```